# Highstock bottom chart not shown

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using one the official highstock chart [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) to create something similar with 2 charts stacked on top of each other. The problem is that the bottom chart (volume) is not displayed [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t9rq1f7/)

A brief explanation of [aapl-ohlc.json](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/aapl-ohlc.json) file will be helpful.

```
...    
const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('ohlc-data').innerHTML);


// split the data set into ohlc and volume
const ohlc = data.map((a) => [a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]])
const volume = data.map((a) => [a[0], a[5]])

// set the allowed units for data grouping
const groupingUnits = [
  [
    'week', // unit name
    [1] // allowed multiples
  ],
  [
    'month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
  ]
]

// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 4,
    inputEnabled: false
  },

  title: {
    text: ''
  },

  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    height: '60%',
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    top: '65%',
    height: '35%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }],

  tooltip: {
    split: true
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'candlestick',
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: ohlc,
    dataGrouping: {
      units: groupingUnits
    }
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    data: volume,
    yAxis: 1,
    dataGrouping: {
      units: groupingUnits
    }
  }],
  navigator: {
    enabled: false

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
const volume = data.map((a) => [a[0], a[5]])
```

Points to an element that doesn't exist. `a[5]` is not defined (there are only five elements to each sub array, no sixth element), therefore you have no `y` values in your data, and therefore no data series to display.

I don't know what data element is supposed to represent volume, but for reference, just to show that it does work, here is an updated fiddle using

```
const volume = data.map((a) => [a[0], a[1]])
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/0t9rq1f7/1/

**EDIT:**

Note that in the demo example that you based your fiddle on, the file that they use is `aapl-ohlcv.json`, not `aapl-ohlc.json`, which does in fact have a 6th data element in each sub array.

- https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/aapl-ohlcv.json